# change Image from BGR to binary image 0,1?

Tags: c#, emgucv

i wonder if it is possible with Emgu Cv to chnage image from BGR to binary image as i try to change the BGR to gray

```
 Image<Bgr, byte> image_pass = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bt1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Maybe give this a try:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> image;
image = image_pass.convert<Gray,Byte>().ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(x), new Gray(255));
imageBox.Image(image);
CvInvoke.cvShowImage("binary", image); //To show in a new Window
```

Where `x` is your threshold value, and `255` the maximum value. 
**This would convert the pixel value to 0 if the** **srcImage(x,y)> threshold or to 255, otherwise**.
You can, obviously, change the threshold and your max values

Comment: And you can also use `image.convert<Gray,Byte>().ThresholdBinary(threshold,maxValue);` instead