# Convert Image to binary

Tags: image, image-processing, connected-components

I want to find the connected components of an image. I'm totally a beginner. Can somebody give me a link to some tutorials for this purpose. Also what is a binary image?. What does the term mean `convert image to binary image`? I'm working in C#.

Comment: You can use OpenCV for this task. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874326/change-image-from-bgr-to-binary-image-0-1

Comment: You can do Connected Component Analysis without needing to write any C or C# and without a compiler just in the Terminal, or at the Command Prompt if on Windows... http://stackoverflow.com/a/28429090/2836621

Comment: There's also a very nice example and explanation here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Answer (score 1):

A binary image is an image that has only two valid pixel values. Usually 1 and 0 or the lowest and highest value withn a bit depth. Like 0 and 255 for 8bit images.

To create binary images from gray scale images you define a function that gives you either one of your two values for each pixel value in your source image.

The most common and simple way is to apply a global threshold.

Often you have to know or specify which of both values is background and which is foreground to get meaningful information out of algorithms that take binary input.

Answer (score 0):

A binary image is an image encoded only with 0 and 1. It allows a better compression, because it uses only 1 bit per pixel. But as the access to a bit is a little bit longer than the access to a byte (8 bits), and as we now have plenty or RAM, people usually work with 8 bits images, and then with binary pixels values of 0 and 255.

For the Connected Component Labeling (and counting), the fastest algorithm is the "Union Find". [On this link](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d480842/general-developpement/algorithme-mathematiques/contribuez/java-etiquettage-composantes-connexes-union-find/) you will find Java (fist post) and C implementations (second post).